# Passing variable or object to the angular2 directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a button in my webapp and I wanna pass a `variable` or `object` to this button with using `@Input`. when I wrote `console.log` for printing out value inside of `waitUntil` on console, it was `undefined`!
where I did go wrong?

here is the code I wrote:

**Loading directive:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[loading]'
})
export class LoadingDirective {

    @Input() waitUntil: any;

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('click') open() {
        console.log(this.waitUntil);
    }
}
```

**usage:**

`loadingStatus` is a variable that have true/false value and it define in the component himself. and also it's available inside form I test it with data-binding

```
<div class="btn-wrap"><button class="btn btn-black" loading [waitUntil]="loadingStatus">submit</button></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a plunker. It works for me